# Evaluate $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \! \exp(-||x||^2) d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have to evaluate $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \! \exp(-||x||^2) d\mu$ as part of another problem.

Can someone give me a hint on how to do this?

Comment: Try to make a change of variable in spherical coordinate

Comment: Since $\exp (-\lVert x\rVert^2) = \prod \exp (-x_k^2)$, it's $$\biggl(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp (-x^2)\,dx\biggr)^n.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\|x\|^2}\,dx =\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-r^2}\cdot\mu\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|=r\}\,dr=C_n\int_{0}^{+\infty}r^{n-1}e^{-r^2}\,dr$$
where
$$ C_n = \frac{n \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)} $$
is the surface area of the unit ball. Since:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}r^{n-1}e^{-r^2}\,dr  =\frac{1}{2}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$
we simply have:

> $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\|x\|^2}\,dx = \pi^{n/2}.$$

That also follows from Fubini's theorem, since:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x_i^2}\,dx_i = \sqrt{\pi}.$$

Comment: The mentioning of Fubini's theorem solved it for me. Thank you.